# Compare two like objects to verify equality

Tags: .net, vb.net, object

I am attempting to compare a bitwise clone object to its parent to check for changes using:

```
If Not objCP.Equals(objCPClone) Then
    'do something
End If
```

and it always compares as not equal even immediately after creating the clone.

How should they be compared to check for changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `Equals` method (and `GetHashCode` along the way) to actually check for equality of all necessary fields or properties. The default implementation (inherited from `Object`) just checks whether the references are the same (i.e. whether they are pointing to the *same* object).